# Coding style (PEP8) - Module level "dunders"

Tags: python, pycharm, pep8, pep

*Definition of "Dunder" (**D**ouble **under**score): http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Dunder*

---

I have a question according the placement of module level "dunders" (like `__all__`, `__version__`, `__author__` etc.) in Python code.

The question came up to me while reading through [PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008) and seeing [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24741141/pycharm-have-author-appear-before-imports) Stack Overflow question.

The accepted answer says:

> `__author__` is a global "variable" and should therefore appear below the imports.

But in the PEP8 section [Module level dunder names](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#module-level-dunder-names) I read the following:

> Module level "dunders" (i.e. names with two leading and two trailing
>   underscores) such as `__all__` , `__author__` , `__version__` , etc. should
>   be placed after the module docstring but before any import statements
>   except from `__future__` imports. Python mandates that future-imports
>   must appear in the module before any other code except docstrings.

The authors also give a code example:

```
"""This is the example module.

This module does stuff.
"""

from __future__ import barry_as_FLUFL

__all__ = ['a', 'b', 'c']
__version__ = '0.1'
__author__ = 'Cardinal Biggles'

import os
import sys
```

But when I put the above into PyCharm, I see this warning (also see the screenshot):

> PEP8: module level import not at top of file

[image: PyCharm ignoring PEP8?]

**Question: What is the correct way/place to store these variables with double underscores?**

Comment: PEP 8 is a living document. Take into account that it could have been *silent* on the subject before.

Comment: @MartijnPieters - Any chance to see when a section was added/changed?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

PEP 8 recently was *updated* to put the location before the imports. See [revision cf8e888b9555](https://hg.python.org/peps/rev/cf8e888b9555), committed on June 7th, 2016:

> Relax `__all__` location.
>
> Put all module level dunders together in the same location, and remove
>   the redundant version bookkeeping information.
>
> Closes #27187.  Patch by Ian Lee.

The text was [further updated the next day](https://hg.python.org/peps/rev/c451868df657) to address the `from __future__ import ...` caveat.

The patch links to [issue #27187](http://bugs.python.org/issue27187), which in turn references [this `pycodestyle` issue](https://github.com/PyCQA/pycodestyle/issues/394), where it was discovered PEP 8 was unclear.

Before this change, as there was no clear guideline on module-level dunder globals, so PyCharm and the other answer were correct *at the time*. I'm not sure how PyCharm implements their PEP 8 checks; if they use the [pycodestyle project](https://pycodestyle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) (the defacto Python style checker), then I'm sure it'll be fixed automatically. Otherwise, perhaps file a bug with them to see this fixed.

Comment: Wow, so fast and clear. Will accept this answer in nine (why so long?) minutes :)
Will anybody notice this change and update the PEP8 checker behaviour in the next time?

Comment: @linusg: the issue was raised by the pycodestyle project, so I'm sure that'll be updated. File a bug with PyCharm if you want it fixed there.

Comment: I'll do some more research in the next days to find out how PEP8 checks are done in PyCharm, and eventually file a bug. I'll edit my question then.

Comment: @AXO: that's just a dupe of https://github.com/PyCQA/pycodestyle/issues/394